# RadioGroup and TextView in a RelativeLayout - RadioGroup is hiding TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiogroup

This is what am trying to accomplish. A `textView` and beneath that a `radioButton` group in which `radioButtons` are added programmatically. Am able to get only the `radioButton` group displayed with `radioButtons` and not the `textView`. `radioButton` group is taking up all the space in layout and `textView` is invisible.

I have looked into numerous posts on stackoverflow.com on formatting and displaying in layout but still could not figure where am making the mistake.

Could you please help me with the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/sample"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @MarkKeen's answer is correct. You should accept it.

Comment: add   android:layout_below="@+id/sample"  liine in your Radio Group

Comment: @Harish - thanks for the reply. I added the change that you suggested and in addition to that modified android:layout_height to "wrap_content" of textView. It now works as expected! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding XML that is working as expected for posterity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=“wrap_content” >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/sample"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sample”
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. There is no 'orientation' property for RelativeLayout, as things are 'Relative' to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but now nothing is getting displayed.

Comment: Change `android:layout_height:`. Your `ListView` is occupying the complete screen because its height is set as `match_parent`.

Comment: @PrerakSola - sorry I could not understand, where should that be changed? In ListView - android:layout_height or Layout android:layout_height. Should that be changed to wrap_content?

Comment: In all the elements, `ListView`, `TextView`, `radioGroup`,  change the `height` value.