# No vertical scrollers displayed in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Following is the layout that am using. Radio buttons to the radio group are added dynamically. Everything is working fine with few radio buttons in the group, with more radio buttons and once the orientation is changed was expecting to see vertical scroller and its not displayed.

Are there any more properties that need to be set to the ListView?

Thanks for the pointer.

If its worth, its an extension to this question posted [RadioGroup and TextView in a RelativeLayout - RadioGroup is hiding TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941902/radiogroup-and-textview-in-a-relativelayout-radiogroup-is-hiding-textview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height=“wrap_content” >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/sample"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sample”
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your listview (at least not the radiogroup we see in your layout) and its height is wrap so 0. RadioGroup is not scrollable by itself, put it in a ScrollView if you want to make it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to surround the `<RadioGroup>` with a `<ScrollView>` like this and it should scroll down/up, because the RadioGroup as itself doesn't scroll by default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
         android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height=“wrap_content” >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/sample"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:background="@color/black"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="@string/sample"
         android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ScrollView 
         android:id="@+id/scrollview_radioGroup"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:layout_below="@id/sample">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sample”
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also, never use wrap_content on the height of a ListView, unless you know what you're doing (which i am not convinced you are).

Comment: and what are you suggesting to set as height of the ListView then??

Comment: well the ListView in this code seems not used, and my comment was more for OP. But your scrollview is the same, it shouldn't be wrapping on content (because it would never scroll). It should be match_parent, or obeying any constraint you can have on your layout (like : below text view for example)

Comment: Think twice - both the listView and ScrollView will be filled in dynamically, so they are not empty and unused. If we set the layout_height to match_parent we won't see the other views in the layout anymore, because the specific view will fill the whole Layout. Have you ever tried it by yourself?

Comment: about height, you ask the final height of the scrollview to be wrapped on it's content, so it has no reason to make the content scroll. If you want to see other things in your layout, it's up to you to put below/above constraints or whatever fits your needs. About the fact the listview is useless : his question is about the fact his listview not scrolling when he has radiobuttons in his group which is not in the list makes me think he has the wrong idea about how listview works and he put one here to make his whole layout scroll (which won't work)

Comment: I understood his/her question like that the radio group doesn't scroll, not his/her listView. I think that the author  of the question use the listView for something different, not for the radio buttons, but he/she could correct me or say if our discussion is useful for him/her.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81188/discussion-between-xavier-falempin-and-gabriella-angelova).

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote in your other post and your "scroll" issue let me suggest you a layout :

"This is what am trying to accomplish. A textView and beneath that a radioButton group in which radioButtons are added programmatically. Am able to get only the radioButton group displayed with radioButtons and not the textView. radioButton group is taking up all the space in layout and textView is invisible."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/sample"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:background="@color/black"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/sample"
     android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ScrollView 
     android:id="@+id/scrollview_radioGroup"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_below="@id/sample">

        <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RadioGroup>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You even should use a LinearLayout instead of your relative if you just have those elements in your layout.